# Java: What is the advantage of using HashMap iterator over ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator, concurrenthashmap

I have a program that is single-threaded that uses a Map where items are removed one by one while iterating. I have read that iterator can be used here to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` but why not use ConcurrentHashMap instead which seems to be much cleaner?

My code:

```
private final Map<Integer, Row> rowMap;


.....

private void shutDown() {

  for (Integer rowNumber : rowMap.keySet()) {
    deleteRow(rowNumber)
  }
}

....
```

For my scenario, using a iterator means declaring it final so closeRow() and deleteRow() methods have access to it for removing it. Additionally, the iterator.remove() method does not return the value of the item being removed which is necessary in my case.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to do it so it doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException? Is it using an iterator or making rowMap a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and provide a [MRE]. There is no `ConcurrentMapException` in the standard Java API. For me, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly straightforward iterator pattern.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,Row>> it = rowMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry<Integer,Row> ent = it.next();
   Integer key = ent.getKey(); 
   Row row = ent.getValue(); // before the remove
   it.remove();
   // ... do what you want with key and row;
}
```

So, we're iterating through the map with an explicit iterator, which allows us to use the iterator's `remove` method during iteration.  We're iterating over the "entry set" view of the map, which allows us to retrieve both key and value from the single iterator.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet--)

> public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
>
> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is
> backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
> vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
> in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or
> through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the
> iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use `ConcurrentHashMap` only if it's shared among threads.

In single thread, `CurrentModificationException` is thrown when the object is modified while an iterator is being used.

There are two ways to remove elements from a collection such as list and map.  One is by calling remove on the collection.  The other is using an iterator.  But they can't be used together.  If you remove an element using the remove method of the collection object, it would invalidate the state of the iterator.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(List.of(1,2,3,4,5));
Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
list.remove(0);
        
while(it.hasNext()){
  System.out.print(it.next());
}
```

Here's the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```